# Node-Red Dashboard and Email Node

Tags: node-red

I am taking a formulare of choices from dashboard in Node-Red I want to mail it to the user using email. I have generated the excel sheet from the formulare. This excel sheet must be mailed using the user mail id provided in the formulare i.e. msg.payload.E_mail.

I tried using function node to send mail as msg.to = msg.payload.E_mail but failed. In the function node I typed the following:

```
msg.to = "xxxxxxx";
msg.topic = "xxxxxxx";
msg.payload = "xxxxxxx";
msg.attachments = [{ filename: 'xxxxxxx.xlsx',
                     path: 'xxxxxxx',
                     content: msg.payload
                  }];
return msg;
```

Then I tried using the Email node in Node-red but it will give only one mail To recipient: which is static and cannot take from user input from dashboard.
Please could anyone suggest alternative method.
Thanks in advance

[image: Below is the node-red flow the function block contains the the above code]

Comment: What is the format of "msg.payload.E_mail"? The "msg.to" needs to be an string with the desired recipients separeted by ",".

Ex: `msg.to = "email1@email.com, email2@email.com"`

Comment: msg.payload.E_mail is a JSON format output from Formular_anmeld in dashboard given by user input in dashboard

Comment: I haven't find this node, Formular_anmeld, to make some tests, can you add a debug node capturing all output before entering on "Setup mail content" and add the data on the question? This way it will be easy to have an idea on how to transform the data in a way that the mail node will accept

Answer (score 0):

found the solution after a sleepless night !
Actually the code is correct I just needed to extract email address from Formular_anmeld as msg.payload. Put the value in function node of Setup mail content

```
msg.to = msg.payload;
```

I have kept the msg.to in the email node as blank. because it will take the value from  the function node and voila !, it works